# server returned an error 405 method not Allowed

Tags: c#

Can anybody please tell me, whenever i call `getLatestCustomerNumber()` procedure
it throws an exception of method not allowed.

User is registered

```
public ActionResult UserRegistration(Customer customer, FormCollection fc)
    {
        try
        {
            var newCustomerNo = "";
            string latestCustomerNo = _com.GetLatestCustomerNo();//this function would b called
            if (latestCustomerNo == null)
            {
                newCustomerNo = "PBC-" + "000001";
            }
            else
            {
                var incrementalPart = latestCustomerNo.Substring(0, 4);
            }
```

After that

```
public string GetLatestCustomerNo()
{
        try
        {
            string result = GetStructure(String.Format("GetLatestCustomerNo"));//this get structure would be called
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(result);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "Error";
        }

}



public string GetStructure(string uri)
{
        string _result = "False";
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(String.Format("{0}/{1}", baseAddress, uri));
    req.Method = "GET";
    req.ContentType = "application/json";
    using (HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            _result = sr1.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    return _result;
}
```

Now the issue is that webhttpResponse isn't getting from server, it throws an exception

Comment: What are the values of baseAddress and uri, also please show the API method definition on the server

Comment: This is the user controller and everytime the user gets register then, the _com.GetLatestCustomerNo() is called and in that GetLatestCustomerNo() function....GetStructure() is called mentioned above

Comment: This is the User Controller

 var newCustomerNo = "";
                string latestCustomerNo = _com.GetLatestCustomerNo();
                if (latestCustomerNo == null)
                {
                    newCustomerNo = "PBC-" + "000001";
                }
                else
                {
                    var incrementalPart = latestCustomerNo.Substring(0, 4);
                }

Comment: Expand your question with everything you put on the comments, properly formatted

Comment: it doesn't even hit on Database

Base Address="http://localhost:34144/EMTService.svc"
Uri= GetLatestCustomerNo

Comment: i hope now it is clear